# Should I say, where are you going to or where are you going?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

On my way home, I met my friend on train. 
I was curious to know where she was heading to, so I asked her

> Where are you going to

I am not sure if it is correct to omit the preposition, to, by simply asking this instead

> Where are you going

Please help me. I am suddenly confused with it.

Thank you.

Comment: Really no difference, but I would leave the "to" in. To me it sounds better, and makes the directional intent clear. For one syllable it doesn't cost much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly fine if you just leave it out.

Both of the phrases are correct although the first is usually used when you know someone is going to a place and the second when you don't know if they are going to an actual place.

Example: Your friend mentions they are going out shopping, you ask "Where are you going to?".

Example 2: Your friend mentions they are just going out, you ask "Where are you going?"

Answer (score 1):

This was the subject of a riddle in the game King's Quest VI. "Where are you going" is a dangling participle, the correct phrase is "Where are you going to?"

That being said, Joyce Carol Oates, the famous short story writer, has a short story with the title "Where are you going, where have you been?"

If you are asking yourself questions about English at this level, you probably have a pretty firm grasp of the language.

Also may read about split infinitives and itinerant/dependent clauses, may help with a bookworm one day.